# How to add subfolder to global-ignores in SVN

Tags: svn, version-control

We have to ignore a subfolder in SVN.
Here is how our projekt looks:

```
Projekt\export\data\
Projekt\export\data\data\
```

The folder that we have to be ignored is \data\data\
But the other folders below in \data\ must be submitted to SVN.

I can not figure out the syntax for this.

Regards,

Marcel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set svn:ignore property for Projekt\export\data (put there "data")

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html

Comment: Okay my question was to unspecific. I have to ignore this while import to SVN. Any possibility's to do this?

Comment: hmm... for now I see only "manual" way - temporarily move data/data somewhere, import and move it back, it may be useful to edit your question - more chances that someone will answer the correct question